# Run local code on remote interpreter (VS CODE)

Tags: python, apache-spark, visual-studio-code, ssh, interpreter

I have some code on my local machine which I want to run with the python interpreter or python present on the remote server.

Purpose of doing it: some part of my code contains some spark code which does not runs on my local machine but the spark code runs fine on remote machine. But the code is not present on the remote machine.

Please mention the solution related to VS CODE

Please help me.

I tried solving it by resolving spark issue but machine is not compatible. Checked few things on remote works fine. I am positive my code can work on remote interpreter. I know pycharm support it in professional version which I cant access. Please help me for VS CODE.

Comment: Send the code as text file, launch it normally?

Comment: Install the "Remote Development" extension pack, create an SSH connection and work on the remote machine as if you were editing a local project.

Answer (score -1):

Please install [Remote-SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) extension in extension store.

Then you can select `Remote-SSH: Connect to Host...` from the Command Palette ( **Ctrl+Shift+P**).

[image]

You could read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_connect-to-a-remote-host) for more details about remote control.